# Conflict when trying to use useEffect to clear states when the component unmounts. React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to use useEffect to clean up states when the component unmounts, but it's interfering when I try to set the states. My code is based on clicking in a client and setting this client id to send in a api request:

```
const setClient = () => {
    setClientIdForRegister(id)
    setClientNameForRegister(nome)
  }

return (
    <ClientSearchResultInfos onClick={setClient}>
      <div className="client_and_email">
        <h2>{nome}</h2>
        <span>{email}</span>
      </div>
      <CaretRight size={30} />
    </ClientSearchResultInfos>
)
```

The request:

```
const handleRegisterReceipt = async (data: FormDataProps) => {
    try {
      const dataToSend = {
        cliente: {
          id: clientIdForRegister,
        },
        dataPagamento: data.dataPagamento,
        valor: data.valor,
      }

      const response = await api.post('/pagamentos', dataToSend)
}
```

When the user clicks in the client it's supposed to set the value of the input of the form with the client's name:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getClientName = async () => {
      if (clientNameForRegister) {
        setValue('cliente', clientNameForRegister)
      }
    }

    getClientName()
  }, [setValue, clientNameForRegister])
```

I triend using return inside the parent's component useEffect, so when I leave the page and come back, the id and name are null again

```
// parent component: 

const cleanUp = () => {
    setClientNameForRegister(null)
    setClientIdForRegister(null)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return cleanUp
  })
```

But this causes the sent clientIdForRegister to always be null, because the component always re-renders and runs cleanUp.

I also tried like this:

```
// parent component:

const isMountedRef = useRef<boolean>(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      isMountedRef.current = false

      if (isMountedRef.current) {
        setClientNameForRegister(null)
        setClientIdForRegister(null)
      }
    }
  })
```

This way doesn't set the clientIdForRegister null, but it doesn't clear the name and id when the component unmounts.

Is there a way I can clear the states every time the user leaves the page and still send the clientIdForRegister?

Comment: For your second attempt, you set isMountedRef.current = false, then check if it is true, and only set null values in that case (which you will never reach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method you tried is the best practice, you just missed ", []" at the end, which resulted going into return on every re-render.

this way return only executes when component unmounts, hence like this will work:

```
const cleanUp = () => {
    setClientNameForRegister(null)
    setClientIdForRegister(null)   
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    return cleanUp()   
    }, [])
```

Comment: It worked using "return cleanUp", without "()". If I use "cleanUp()" it only sets the values null the second time I enter the page after choosing a client. I don't know the reason why, but will look into it. Thanks for your help!